# Compiling and testing Solana programs on Apple Silicon (M1, M2, M3)

Tags: m1

How do you compile and test Solana programs on Apple Silicon? How do you get programs and tests with zero-copy structs to work?

Zero-copy structs are structs that do not require copy to deserialize or serialize. Instead, they  are directly referenced in memory. For example:

```
let foo: &Foo = bytemuck::try_from_bytes(foo_account_info.try_borrow_data()?).map_err(...)?;
```

The benefits are twofold:

1. No compute is spent on deserialization (aside from runtime checks of `try_borrow_*`).
2. No/constant use of stack space. The stack size limit in Solana is much smaller than off-chain programs. Many protocols that live on mainnet use structs that are simply too large to fit on the stack — think exchange account metadata, for example. These structs *cannot* be loaded onto the stack because they are too large. Zero-copy is one way of working with such structs.

Comment: For completeness sake (considering this is a question you answered yourself) could you add an example program of 'zero-copy structs'? Because in my case, compiling and testing Solana programs on Apple Silicon 'just works', without any manual steps. There might be something special with the zero-copy struct that's different and that should ideally be in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- M3 uses ARM's aarch64 architecture
- Apple ships optional software called Rosetta 2 which translates x86_64 binaries to aarch64, either when loading the binary or dynamically at runtime. This allows Apple Silicon (M1, M2, M3, etc.) to run x86_64 binaries.
- The Solana uses the BPF vm, which has its own bytecode distinct from both native x86_64 and aarch64. The layout of structs in memory in the BPF vm is essentially the same as x86_64 and often times different than aarch64.
- In order to get Solana programs and tests to properly compile and run on Apple Silicon, I needed the off-chain code to target the x86_64 architecture, so I could load zero-copy structs off-chain. I did that with these three steps:

1. Ensure Rosetta 2 is installed.
2. I targeted x86_64 for the specific Cargo project by writing the file $PROJECT_ROOT/.cargo/config.toml:

```
[build]
target = "x86_64-apple-darwin
```

If you don't target x86_64, you could end up with an error like this:

```
error[E0512]: cannot transmute between types of different sizes, or dependently-sized types
```

...with further mention of the source type size in bits and the target type size in bits. The error is basically telling you the compiler wants to compile a program with a struct (perhaps one that uses `repr(C)`) but that representation is NOT how your computer's architecture requires it to be laid out in memory.

3. If you try to compile with just that step and nothing else, you will get a bunch of errors about the standard library, such as `Ok` and `Err` and other parts of the standard library not being defined. This is a poorly-conveyed error indicating that you need to add the `x86_64-apple-darwin` target to your rustup toolchain:

```
rustup target add x86_64-apple-darwin
```

Oila!

Comment: For increased SEO, it would be good if you could share examples of the 'bunch of crazy errors' you will get. This way, it will be useful for a dev that searches the error message.